# How (or can I) have a GTK application to open in a console?

Tags: console, gtk, opencv

My use case is that I have built a GTK based application (opencv) in Debian Jessie light which boots only in console mode. While Jessie light is for the raspberry pi, I believe my question applies to any linux distribution. 
When I try to run some of the examples, I get: 
`error: Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display`.

I have installed `libgtk2.0-dev` and opencv was built with the option `WITH_GTK=ON`.

So what is the minimum requirement so that I be able to run a GTK application in console mode? If this isn't possible, then what is the next step to take: install `xorg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GTK+2 supports a DirectFB backend for GDK; if your application only uses GTK+2 (not GTK+3 as far as I can tell), then you might be able to get it working on the console by building a DirectFB-enabled GTK+2 library. (Use `--with-gdktarget=directfb` with the `configure` script.)

Failing that, you will need to install an X server and run that (`xorg`).

Comment: Having already recompiled several times opencv, at ~70mn per build, I will try the option DirectFB option at a later time. But this is very interesting and worth a test. Otherwise I couldn't find any information on the possibility to have GTK to open in a console unless xorg was installed (which I eventually did, and you confirm it's required).